# Scala catching confusion

Tags: exception, scala

I've recently seen code like this:

```
val maybeInt = catching(classOf[NFE]) opt arg.toInt
```

What is this `opt`? An Option? Why isn't it using getOrElse to extract the value? In the above code, will `maybeInt` be None if a NumberFormatException gets thrown?

Comment: Hey, that code is familiar! :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`catching` looks like it's some sort of method call, doesn't it?  It is, but it actually returns an instance of a class `Catch`; it doesn't directly take an argument.  This class has two methods that are particularly useful for dealing with exceptions (and several more for catching multiple exceptions).  The first is

```
def opt [U >: T] (body: ⇒ U) : Option[U]
```

which is being used here--you give it something that may throw an exception, and it will return `Some(result)` if everything went okay, and `None` if the targeted exception was caught:

```
scala> type NFE = NumberFormatException
defined type alias NFE

scala> import scala.util.control.Exception._
import scala.util.control.Exception._

scala> catching(classOf[NFE]).opt( "fish".toInt )
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> catching(classOf[NFE]).opt( "42".toInt )  
res1: Option[Int] = Some(42)
```

You can then deal with this with `map` or `filter` or `getOrElse` or whatever else you use to deal with options.

The other useful method is `either`, which returns an instance of `Left(exception)` if an exception was thrown, and a `Right(result)` if it was not:

```
scala> catching(classOf[NFE]).either( "fish".toInt )
res2: Either[Throwable,Int] = Left(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fish")

scala> catching(classOf[NFE]).either( "42".toInt )
res3: Either[Throwable,Int] = Right(42)
```

You can then use `fold` or map to an option or whatever else you like doing with eithers.

Note that you can define a single catcher and use it multiple times (so you don't need to create the catcher object every time you, for example, parse an integer):

```
scala> val catcher = catching(classOf[NFE])
catcher: util.control.Exception.Catch[Nothing] = Catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException)

scala> catcher.opt("42".toInt)
res4: Option[Int] = Some(42)

scala> catcher.opt("fish".toInt)
res5: Option[Int] = None
```

---

Edit: as Daniel points out in the comments, this still creates a temporary `Catch[Option]`; given the method signatures, there isn't an easy way to just have it trap exceptions and generate options without creating any extra objects.  This reminds me why I write my own methods to do exactly that:

```
def optNFE[T](t: => T) = try { Some(t) } catch {case nfe: NFE => None}
optNFE( "fish".toInt )  // gives None
optNFE( "42".toInt ) // gives Some(42)
```

Comment: This is really handy.  No idea it existed.  Thanks for the writeup.

Comment: Actually, `catching` won't return `Catch[NFE]`, but `Catch[Nothing]`. The type parameter or `Catch` indicates what it may return in case of exception. For instance, `withApply` takes a function `Throwable => U`, and returns a `Catch[U]`. The method `opt` will first use `toOption` to get a `Catch[Option[X]]` which returns `None` if an exception is thrown, and then pass `Some(body)` to that catcher.

Comment: @RexKerr Why is the return type of `catching(classOf[NFE]).either( "fish".toInt )` `Either[Throwable,Int]` and not `Either[java.lang.NumberFormatException,Int]` ?

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama - It is possible to create something similar that preserves the type of the exception, but this one can catch an arbitrary number: `def catching[T](exceptions: Class[_]*): Catch[T]`.  In the absence of first-class union types, it's best just to specify the common superclass `Throwable`.

Answer (score 1):

I use a more simple pattern when there is only one catch :

```
 try{
      return args.split(" ").exists(line.startsWith _)
 }catch {
    case _ =>{//generic exception
      logger.error("Error with line ${line} for ${ex.message}")
      throw _
    }    
 }
```

I'm definitely not yet a Scala pro, and I guess you could find shorter stuff